# What are some good online sources for recipes?

Tags: beer, cider, recipe, mead, wine

What are some good online sources for recipes? Please specify the type of recipes the site has (extract, all-grain, mead, cider, etc.).

Comment: Should be CW since there's no single "right" answer.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11/recipe-questions/13#13

Comment: I'm not using the "beer" tag for this question because I'm hoping it will become a community wiki that will have pointers to all kinds of recipes, not just beer recipes.

Comment: Okay, changed my mind based on discussion in the comments here: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-tag-questions-as-beer-brewing-or-wine-making/9#9

Comment: Here is another site: [Brewtoad](https://www.brewtoad.com/)

Answer (score 9):

[Hopville](http://hopville.com) lets you save recipes... it's not just a source of them, I often find that I can't find *exactly* the ingredients in a recipe. Also it will guesstimate Initial and Final gravity, color and other useful information.

Comment: It is, in fact, a source of recipes.

Comment: Fair enough. Reword slightly.

Comment: Down, currently

Answer (score 4):

Try these for beer recipes:

[Homebrew Beer Recipes & Great Clone Beer Recipes](http://beerrecipes.org/)

[The Brewery Home Spreadsheet Recipes Discussion](http://www.hbd.org/recipator/)

[Tasty Brew](http://www.tastybrew.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit to add the types of recipes?

Comment: Both hbd and Tastybrew have many recipes that have never actually been brewed and might have serious issues.  I'd advise you to stay away from both.

Comment: I am with Denny.  Online recipe sources are so hard to trust.  Best to just brew something yourself out of a book or mag, then learn to tweak the recipe to what you really like.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some Jamil Zainasheff Beer recpies

[Jamil Recipes](http://beerdujour.com/JamilsRecipes.htm)

[Jamil's Brewing Network Recipes](http://beerdujour.com/JamilsBrewingNetworkRecipes.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I find this forum to have some good beer recipes. Two of the good threads below

http://www.jimsbeerkit.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8174

http://www.jimsbeerkit.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12097

Answer (score 3):

Beer, mead, cider, and wine recipes, including national award winners...

See these [recipes](http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/Recipes) from the American Homebrewing Association.

Answer (score 3):

There are some great ones in the [HomeBrewTalk Recipe Database](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f82/).

[Northern Brewer](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/brewing) posts all of the recipes for its kits.

Both sites have a good number of reviews for many of the recipes.

Answer (score 2):

I see I'm a bit late in the game here, but I would nonetheless recommend [Brewtoad](http://www.brewtoad.com) to anyone who's looking for new recipes or would like to share theirs.

You can post recipes to share or browse recipes posted by other brewers. It's a really neat site with excellent UI/UX. You can even see what color your beer will be as you tweak your ingredients, and once you've settled on a recipe you can order the supplies in a snap.

Comment: Very useful tools here for formulating your own recipe or finding and tweaking someone else's recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just started a site for Cider brewing and adding my tested recipes frequently. Please take a look and let me know what you think.

[Index of homebrewing](http://www.hoodconsultinggroup.com/homebrewing/)

Answer (score 1):

Brewers friend has a nice list of recipes that you can look through and sort by many different criteria. They have tons of useful calculators and a recipe designer as well.

- [Brewers Friend](http://www.brewersfriend.com/)
- [Recipe Database](http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/beer/)
- [Recipe Designer](http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/calculator/)

There are tons of other useful things on that site besides what I have listed above, but those are the places I go most often there.