# Need a simple extract IPA recipe

Tags: recipe, recipe-formulation

I am looking for a simple IPA recipe that I can use with DME (and any other simple/easy ingredients). I've never done my own recipe and have no idea of the different hop characters, so I don't want something that adds 5 different hops at 5 stages and leaves me with no idea to what contributes what to the beer. The ideal would be something that maybe only has 1 or 2 hops.

Ideally I could brew it in small batches and then tweak and improve the recipe over time. This will let me understand the effects of the changes in the beer with each batch. So any further suggestions for how to develop the recipe wold be great.

Comment: Would be very helpful if hops were available from my LHBS http://www.brewstore.co.uk/hops-132-c.asp

Comment: Our aim is not to be yet-another-recipe-site.  Here's a list of resources:   http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-are-some-good-online-sources-for-recipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an American NW style IPA and based upon your hop choices I would say use Citra and Cascade. Made up a recipe for you on hopville. Check it out and let me know if you have any questions:

http://hopville.com/recipe/1677798

I suggested using the American Ale II yeast, but doesn't look like they sell that at your HB store. So substitute for whatever you like British Ale or London Ale Wyeast, or your favorite dry yeast.

This should give you a good starting point and you can tweak it from there. Challenger would be another hop you could try putting in as well. Or you could try substituting for one of the British hops. If you could get your hands on some Centennial that is a major player over here in the US in most beers. That and simcoe. Good luck and if you don't have a Hopville account get one it is great place to put your recipes so you don't lose them.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great help. Could you explain what the crystal malt brings to the beer?

Comment: Hopville realy helped. Based off your recipe, I scaled it down to a small batch and ultra-simplified it to an all DME recipe http://hopville.com/recipe/1677924 . I probably won't bother with that one, but will start with version 2 http://hopville.com/recipe/1677924 . I've been reading a bit of sugar helps dry it out a little and I like the look of that little extra bump of ABV

Comment: Your recipes look fine. The Crystal 60L is just for color. Your substitution of Amber DME solves that problem nicely. And sticking with cascade should be nice beer. The citra would add a nice citrusy hop flavor. But that could be a tweak you try later. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that I don't like Hopville because it doesn't take into account the boil size when determining IBU calculations.  It gives the same IBU with a 5 gal boil and a 2 gal boil.  For example, the same recipe using BrewersFriend with a 5gal boil comes to 61.56 IBU instead of 67.6 IBU (http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/30855/hopville-conversion).  If you drop down to a partial boil like 3gal you're only getting 41.6 IBU.  I tend to start my boils with 6-6.5 gallons so I finish right around 5 gallons of wort.  It also allows you to save money on hops since you don't need to use as much for bittering.

I also recommend using the Safale US-05 yeast for your IPA.  It's a wonderful yeast, easy to use (just rehydrate), ferments wonderfully, and finishes nicely in my IPAs.  I did have to use a blow-off tube on my last West Coast IPA though.

Comment: The issue with Hopville hasn't been an issue for me as I always do full boils. But I could see how it could be. It would be a good point to bring up with the creator of Hopville. He was very responsive when I reported a bug to him. He could add it to his list of feature requests. Do you want to e-mail him or should I?